# Message dialog if PHP function successful or not

Tags: php, function, messagebox

I have a PHP function that checks some data before inserting it into the DB.
For now I have thees messages that inside my php function that display, wherever I am calling the function. ex: div.
I would like instead of the small message inside the div, to have a message box that will display the message. How can I do this? Thanks

```
if($u_l_name == $dbuser_last_name and $u_name == $dbuser_first_name)
            {
                echo "Record Exists Already";
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt2 = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO employers (user_password, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_DOB, user_address, user_email, user_phone, user_gender, user_position, user_contract_type, user_contract_hours) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt2->bind_param("ssssssssssi", $u_password, $u_name, $u_l_name, $u_DOB, $u_address, $u_email, $u_phone, $u_gender, $u_position, $u_contract_type, $u_contract_hours);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->close();
                echo "Record Added Succesfully";
            }
```

Function call:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitButton']))
        {    
         $admin_query->addEmployerData($u_password, $u_name, $u_l_name, $u_DOB, $u_address, $u_email, $u_phone, $u_gender, $u_position, $u_contract_type, $u_contract_hours);

        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Javascript [alert](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp) method? if yes here is how you can do it:

```
$message;
if($u_l_name == $dbuser_last_name and $u_name == $dbuser_first_name)
            {
                $message = "Record Exists Already";
            }
            else
            {
                $stmt2 = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO employers (user_password, user_first_name, user_last_name, user_DOB, user_address, user_email, user_phone, user_gender, user_position, user_contract_type, user_contract_hours) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $stmt2->bind_param("ssssssssssi", $u_password, $u_name, $u_l_name, $u_DOB, $u_address, $u_email, $u_phone, $u_gender, $u_position, $u_contract_type, $u_contract_hours);
                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->close();
                $message = "Record Added Succesfully";
            } 
            echo "<script>alert('$message')</script>";
```